# How to adapt path of links for localhost on TYPO3-9.5.31?

Tags: path, hyperlink, typo3-9.x

In the TYPO3 v9.5 project, installed on XAMPP. The links to file addresses do not contain "project_name/public".

I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/fileadmin/templates/css/fonts.css?1580323512" media="all">
```

I need:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/project_name/public/fileadmin/templates/css/fonts.css?1580323512" media="all">
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the problem:
Add a line to public\fileadmin\templates\typoscript\page\page.ts: `page.config.absRefPrefix = http://localhost/project_name/public/`